# Gremlin - search for multiple substrings

Tags: gremlin, janusgraph, gremlinpython

For a given vertex, I can find whether a property `myproperty` contains *a single* substring `substring1`, as so:

```
g.V(993280096)
    .filter({it.get().value("myproperty").contains("substring1")})
```

How can I extend this to search for *multiple* substrings in the same query?

Something along the lines of:

```
g.V(993280096)
    .filter({ it.get().value("myproperty")
                .contains(or("substring1", "substring2"))})
```

And is there a better way to do this instead of using lambda expressions? Note that I do not want to use the graph database (in my case JanusGraph) builtins because I'm using gremlin-python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the new text filter predicates. On the modern sample graph you could do this for example:

```
gremlin> TinkerFactory.createModern().traversal().V().
           has("name", containing("ark").or(containing("os"))).values("name")
==>marko
==>josh
```

Answer (score 0):

Just after posting I identified a solution (though I don't know if this is the best way) using `matches` instead of `contains`:

```
g.V(993280096)
    .filter({ it.get().value("myproperty").matches(".* substring1.*|.* substring2.*")})
```